# the versions of the .net framework configuration provider (machineConfig64) are different on the source (2.0) and destination (4.0)

Tags: .net, iis, windows-server-2012, webdeploy

I'm using Web Deploy 3.5 to sync websites from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2012 R2 but I keep getting the following error:
**the versions of the .net framework configuration provider (machineConfig64) are different on the source (2.0) and destination (4.0)**

I followed the instructions from this [website](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/fred/how-to-migrate-all-your-sites-using-web-deploy/).

I tried removing the 2.0 references from Msdeploy.exe.config and Msdepsvc.exe.config on both the source and destination servers but I still get the same error.

Any ideas??

Comment: I know you wrote this 3 years ago but I am facing exactly the same issue and I've tried everything like you explained in your question. Did you manage to do it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (pull mode):

```
msdeploy
-verb:sync 
-source:apphostconfig="WEB SITE",
computername=https://SRC_SERVER:8172/msdeploy.axd,
authtype=Basic,
username=USERNAME,
password=PASSWORD
-dest:apphostconfig="WEB SITE" 
-allowUntrusted 
-disableLink:FrameworkConfigExtension 
-enableLink:AppPool
```

New lines are for readability